# How do you Upgrade Ubuntu from an ISO Image By Mounting as Loopback (without burning)

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, mount, iso-image, loopback

I'm trying to upgrade 9.10 without burning the ISO image to a disk. What are the steps to get this to work?

I am using the `Ubuntu-9.10-desktop-amd64.iso` image.

There are a few postings around on this, but none of them work for 9.10.

Comment: As always with any operating system I would advise a clean install wherever possible. There are enough people with Karmic upgrade problems in the forum that I wouldn't consider it foolproof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to perform the udpate you need the **alternate CD** that you can download from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/downloadmirrors#alternate).

You can find all the relevant instructions on how to perform the upgrade [on the official ubuntu site](http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/upgrading). Of course you do not need to burn the actual CD or DVD. Once mounted, an ISO is no different than the real thing, in this case.

If you are more of a GUI than of a CLI type, then you can mount the .iso image by installing either of these two applications (both in the standard repos and they are substantially identical to your purpose):

- [gisomount](https://launchpad.net/gisomount)
- [gmountiso](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gmountiso)

It's very easy. You won't have problems, you'll see! :)

HTH, mac.

Answer (score 4):

Mount the ISO like so:

```
sudo mount -o loop ~/Desktop/ubuntu-9.10-i386.iso /media/cdrom0
```

(replace the paths to the ISO as required)

This dialog should pop up:

[image]

You can then follow the on-screen instructions. If it doesn't pop up, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and run:

```
gksu "sh /cdrom/cdromupgrade"
```

---

However if you have a network connection you can also navigate to **System -> Administration -> Update Manager** then check for updates and grab the upgrade.

Comment: From your steps, there is no '/cdrom' directory. There is also no 'cdromupgrade' file at the root of the ISO image.

Comment: well not that you specified which image you're using....it can't be done with this method for that image, you need the alternate CD for this.

Comment: @JohnT worked for me.  I assumed alternate cd.  wasn't that the question, how to mount install media and upgrade from it?

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is an upgrade to version 9.10, the very first thing to do is a full backup, of course.

If you want to save yourself from burning a CD, but have some SD memory card around, you can try to put the ISO as the operating system card on the SD card, and boot from it.

UNETBOOTIN is a small program, running under Linux, that can take an ISO file, and put it on t an SD card, so you can boot from it (if oyur computer BIOS lets you do this, of course). Once you're done installing Ubuntu, you can re-format your card and use it again as a usual storage device.

Note that you need to provide root credentials (sudo) to use unetbootin, and that it is recommedned to freshly partition your SD card before actually installing the ISO using unetbootin.

Just google for unetbootin, and you will find it.

JF